# Updating Kubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 19.10

yesterday I noticed that the 19.10 release of Kubuntu was not available from terminal running this

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

So I did this instead.

I searched for:

```
ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt_19.10.15_all.deb
```

So I added:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe
```

Via the Ubuntu website

After that I updated every package on Discover now it says that my kubuntu version is 19.10.

Did I make a mistake? Will my system blow up soon? It's like I updated everything manually but I am wondering if I did it right.

Comment: It's probably not the way to do it:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EoanUpgrades/Kubuntu. ...so if the world goes up in flames, we'll know who to blame.

Comment: Yeah, this is not the supported way to update but it does work sometimes. I've ran into problems doing this in the past but it was nothing that a few `sudo apt -f install` commands couldn't fix. You might also want to make sure that you also have the lines for "security" and "updates" so that you don't miss out on any security updates and bug fixes.

Comment: For now it works (apart from some random errors sometimes.) Can you explain me what's the function of that command? (I am a noob). Should I do something?